# find out if sentenceA contain sentenceB python

Tags: python

I have list of sentence like this

```
Senctence_List = [
    'my name is john',
    'milad is out',
    'ali see you',
]
```

What is the best way to check if `sentenceA` contains one of the `Senctence_List` items

```
sentenceA = 'Hi How Are You today? my name is john'
```

I used this but it's not working for my problem

```
sentenceA = 'Hi How Are You today? my name is john'

for k in Senctence_List:
    if sentenceA.find(k) > -1:
        print(k)
```

Comment: Simply `if b in a`...

Comment: `any(x in sentenceA for x in Senctence_List)` if all you want to do is find out if it's in any of the sentences. Your example suggests that you want to print also. Then the given answer by @say_my_name is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `in` will do this for you,

```
sentenceA = 'Hi How Are You today? my name is john'
Senctence_List = [
    'my name is john',
    'milad is out',
    'ali see you',
]

for k in Senctence_List:
    if k in sentenceA :
        print(k)
```

**Oneline Solution:**

```
print(*[k for k in Senctence_List if k in sentenceA])
```

**Output:**

```
my name is john
```